# Why do we have the following equality?

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a reflexive space. Let $\phi \in X^{***}$, $\psi\in X^{**}$ and $Q_X:X\to X^{**}$ be defined as $Q_X(x)x^*=x^*(x)$ for $x\in X$ and $x^*\in X^*$. Why do we have
$$\psi(\phi\circ Q_X)=(\phi\circ Q_X)(Q^{-1}_X(\psi))?$$
Thanks!

Comment: If $X$ is reflexive $Q_X$ is an isomorphism. So $\psi( v) = Q_X (Q_X^{-1}(\psi))\ (v) = v(Q_X^{-1}(\psi))$. Now let $v= \phi\circ Q_X$.

Comment: I see. Thank you!